# Open/Elastic Search DQL to filter where field exists and non-empty

Tags: elasticsearch, opensearch

As documented https://opensearch.org/docs/latest/dashboards/discover/dql/, We can filter the data based on if the field exists as below

```
name:*
```

The above will filter the results where the name field exists. This name field can be empty also.
But I want to consider only the results where the name field is also non-empty.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 1):

According to the filter editor:

[image: OpenSearch filter editor UI with field=Name, Operator=is not, value=""]
[image: OpenSearch filter display UI, showing 'NOT name:""']

the syntax seems to be:

```
NOT name:""
```

This is with OpenSearch v2.5.0